# how to expose pulsar broker to out side of k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, apache-pulsar

I have installed pulsar helm charts using this link https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/2.10.x/getting-started-helm/. I am trying to expose the broker with nodeport option. I tried to add the node port to Pulsar broker and Pulsar proxy but non of them got worked. Here My requirement is need to push the data using java client on k8s pulsar broker.

Thanks in advance.